# Why are cross expectations zero in MLE?

Tags: statistics, expectation, maximum-likelihood

Let $z_i = (y_i, x_i')'$ be an i.i.d sample of $N$ observations and let $z_i$ have density of the form:
$$f(z_i \mid \theta_0) = f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0) f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)$$
Consider the joint MLE estimator:
$$\widehat{\theta}_J = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \ln(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0) f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0))$$
Now consider the information matrix $I_J$, which is equal to:
$$I_J  = -\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2 \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0) \right)}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta'} \right] \\
 = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right) }{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'} \right] $$
One can further decompose the previous expression as:
$$I_J  = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} +\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta}\right) \left(\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'} +\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right)\right] \\
 = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'} \right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right] \\
 {} + \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial  \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'} \right] $$
I am told that the cross product expectations are equal to zero, that is, 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial  \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right]= 0 $$
Why is this the case?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $z_i$ or $y_i$ on the left hand side of your first expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and clean this up later, but it should be correct. There are some regularity conditions on the score function of $f_1(y|x,\theta)$ that I need to show.

We want to show that :
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_2(x_i \mid \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial  \ln\left(f_1(y_i \mid x_i, \theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta'}\right]= 0
\end{equation}

The derivative of the cross terms is:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{f_1(y|x,\theta)f_2(x|\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f_1(y|x,\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}f_2(x|\theta')\right] \hspace{2mm} \& \hspace{2mm}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{f_1(y|x,\theta)f_2(x|\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}f_1(y|x,\theta')\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f_2(x|\theta)\right]
\end{equation}

If you take the expectation of $h(x,y)$ you're evaluating $\int_{\mathcal{X,Y}}h(x,y)f_1(y|x,\theta)f_2(x|\theta)$. Canceling out the $f_2(x|\theta)$ in the expectation and the fractional part of the partial derivative:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{X,Y}}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f_1(y|x,\theta)}{f_1(y|x,\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}f_2(x|\theta')f_1(y|x,\theta) dxdy \hspace{2mm} \& \hspace{2mm} \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}f_1(y|x,\theta)}{f_1(y|x,\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f_2(x|\theta)f_1(y|x,\theta) dxdy
\end{equation}
Taking first the integral with respect to $Y$:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{X}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}f_2(x|\theta)\int_{\mathcal{Y}}-V_{f_1}(\theta',X)f_1(y|x,\theta) dydx \hspace{2mm} \& \hspace{2mm} \int_{\mathcal{X}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'} f_2(x|\theta)\int_{\mathcal{Y}}-V_{f_1}(\theta,X)f_1(y|x,\theta) dydx
\end{equation}

we have that the $Y$ integral is the integral of the score function of $f_1$, which, under some regularity conditions [is equal to 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)#Mean).

This doesn't work on the cross terms because when you evaluate the derivatives instead of getting the score function you obtain the product of two score functions.

**Edit: Regularity conditions for expected score to be 0**.

1. For all $\theta \in \Theta$ where $\Theta$ denotes the parameter space the density is integrable.
2. Almost surely the score exists, or almost surely the log likelihood is differentiable in $\theta$.
3. There is an integrable function $g(\theta)$ such that for all $\theta$ and $Y$ almost surely $|-V(\theta,Y)| \leq g(\theta)$

I was trying to give more explicit conditions such that the third property was satisfied, but was having some trouble. It should be related to the existence of a unique MLE or something to that effect.